# PHP $_POST from Multiple Dropdown Box Form Submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

I already use multiple dropdown box with data from MySQL database, but I face problem when I try to $_POST it.
This is the code I use:

```js
<?php try {
    $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhost_name . ';dbname=' . $database, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

                        $sql = "SELECT city FROM dropdown";?>
                          
                        <select name="cities" multiple="multiple">
                          
                        <?php foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
                        echo "<option value=>$row[city]</option>";
                        }                        
                        ?>
                            
                        </select></td>
```

This is the code I try to call it:

```html
$test = $_POST['cities'];
echo $test;
```

- The data successfully imported from database but it's doesn't $_POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your form `method` is set to `POST`.

```
<form action="..." method="post">
```

And also, you're best to set the `select` name as an array to store said selections:

```
<select name="cities[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Not to mention that your actual options within this select **need** values...otherwise they'd come up empty.

```
<option value="YOUR VALUE HERE..">...</option>
```

Comment: Thnx, It's work when I add value: echo "<option value=$row[city]>$row[city]</option>";

Comment: Did you do the other stuff I showed you? Change `cities` to `cities[]` then Loop through -> `foreach($_POST['cities'] as $city) { echo $city; }`

Comment: @SamirJunaid perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Use Post Method

```html
<form action="..." method="post">
```